# android modified su binary failes on setgid

Tags: android, linux, android-source

I have created a custom su binary for testing purposes.

I have copied the binary to /system/xbin/mod_su

I have changed the files permissions with chmod 6755 /system/xbin/mod_su,

but still when I run the binary as a non-root user I fail on setgid(0) with 'Operation not permitted1'

Any ideas why this could happen ?

isn't 6755 permmisons enough ?

Comment: You should be aware that it's the file's ownership and mode bits which *originally* and automatically result in the program running as the superuser, not any operations performed by the program itself (though once running as the superuser, the program can chose to become a less privileged one).

Answer (score 1):

Did you chown root.root it before chmod?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from chown you can also try

```
chmod 4755
```

The 4 specifies set user ID which can be the reason for the error.

Comment: But a value of `6` would imply that the `4` (2^2) bit is already set (along with the `2` bit, 2^1). In other words, the the setuid and setgid bits are both set in the original example where `6` is used.

Comment: In some cases too permissive mode would prevent things from working properly. this may be the case this time.